# When i try to write to an address 1 byte up with a loop it corrupts the variable asm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

Im trying to do a loop in NASM that simply writes to a variable 1 and then do it again but 1 byte up on the variable... i have come up with this design

```
    mov ebx, 0
    mov rax, 1
    test_loop:
    cmp ebx, 4
    je test_loop_end
    mov [numbet_to_text + ebx], al
    inc ebx
    jmp test_loop
    test_loop_end:
```

but when i check it with this, it doesn't call:

```
    mov ebx, [numbet_to_text]
    cmp ebx, 1111
    je teste
```

---

Checked with gdb and saw that when i wrote to a byte after writing one of them it got corrupted so...
write to byte 0 --->1 ok, but when I write to byte up I would get
byte 0----> random value.. and byte 1 ----> 1

some GDB screenshots to explain myself better:
[print1](https://prnt.sc/NRAR5F4UDQH-) [print2](https://prnt.sc/x7TLTHyOeDpr)

as you see on the print when i write to 0x40201b i got a 1... thats ok... but when i write a byte up i would get 0x40201c 1... ok but 0x40201b would get a random value in this case 257 and i cant see why

Comment: GDB is probably reading 4 bytes and treating it as a 4-byte number. Bytes 1 1 0 0 makes number 257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov ebx, [numbet_to_text]
> cmp ebx, 1111
> je teste
> ```

After having writen 4 consecutive **bytes** in the memory at *numbet_to_text*, the value that you can expect would be 0x01010101. Certainly not the decimal number 1111.

```
0x40201B contains byte 0x01
0x40201C contains byte 0x01
0x40201D contains byte 0x01
0x40201E contains byte 0x01
```

After the 1st write 0x40201B shows 0x00000001   (1)
After the 2nd write 0x40201B shows 0x00000101   (257)
After the 3rd write 0x40201B shows 0x00010101   (65793)
After the 4th write 0x40201B shows 0x01010101

---

> ```
> mov rax, 1
> mov [numbet_to_text + ebx], al
> ```

If there's any chance that this is 64-bit code then better write:

```
mov [numbet_to_text + rbx], al
```

Comment: thx man really appreciate the answer :D